# Do I stay in the MUC when pause() and attach()?

Tags: xmpp, strophe

I have a client written using Strophe that is loaded on every page on my website. To minimize latency I save the rid, the jid and the sid at each page change so that I can use Strophe's attach() method.

However, I am unsure of if the pausing and attaching keeps me in the MUC. If it does, is there a patch to the Strophe MUC plugin that lets me set handlers without rejoining the MUC?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you do. BOSH pause and attach leaves your stream open, the XMPP server does not even know it happened (since it happens at the BOSH layer).

Pausing is just a graceful way of telling the BOSH connection manager not to expect requests from you for a short period of time. In BOSH it is not necessary to keep a HTTP request open at all times to keep the XMPP stream alive, only that you make requests often enough for the connection manager to be satisfied that you have not gone offline without warning.